# browserify bundle doesn't handle importing files via relative path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am using browserify and babel to compile and bundle my react app. The files from `client/` are bundled up into a single file `static/bundle.js`. But I use a relative import which seems to not be handled correctly.

Here's my file structure

```
client/
    components/
        main.js
    App.js
static/
    bundle.js
gulpfile.js
```

and here's my gulpfile and the offending import

```
// client/App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/main.js';


render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);


// gulpfile.js

var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('build', function() {
  browserify({
    entries: 'client/App.js',
    extensions: ['.js'],
    debug: true
  })
    .transform(babelify, {presets: ['es2015', 'react']})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('static'));
});
```

The problem is the line `import App from './components/main.js';`.

When I look in `static/bundle.js`, there is a line `var _main = require('./components/main.js');`, which doesn't make sense because relative to `bundle.js` there is no `./components/main.js`. That was defined relative to `client/App.js`.

Does browserify not handle such things and is there another tool I should be using in addition, or am I doing something else incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `paths` to your browserify options. If you do not add that browserify doesn't know where to look for to find your module.

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
  grunt.initConfig({

    browserify: {
      options:{
        browserifyOptions: {

          // ...
          paths: [
            './node_modules',
            './client'
          ]

        }
      },
      // ...
    },
    // ...
  });
}
```

This was an [issue](https://github.com/vigetlabs/gulp-starter/issues/17) before they solve it.

Comment: I may have mislead by using the word "module". I just want to import from another file of mine, not necessarily a directory with an `index.js` (updated title to not have the word "module"). It seems to me this changes the answer.

Comment: not necessarily, do you have the paths in options or not?